# Off-chain local storage map?

Tags: offchain-storage, storagemap

I have an off-chain worker that needs to write a `HashMap<u64,Vec<u64>>` to local storage.  I can see how to write a single value using `StorageValueRef` and how I could possibly store a `HashMap` with it.  However, storing a large map (thousands of keys) as a single value is not efficient.  I don't think I can use `StorageMap` for off-chain local storage but that's the functionality I am looking for.  What should I use?

Comment: You can store that HashMap as a value inside storagevalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't an implemented `OffchainStorageMap` for you.

But you could follow this to build your off-chain storage map. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/61b9a4d1a8a9bf39c1d89a8dd02f82785c10860c/frame/merkle-mountain-range/src/lib.rs#L289-L297

You just need to define a way to calculate the **unique** keys for those values.